# Accept INVITE only after REGISTER

Tags: asterisk

I run my own sip server (asterisk).  Apparently my sip server allows to perform an INVITE without doing any REGISTER first.  This leads to lots of unsuccessful attacks on my server.  IS there any way to allow INVITE requests only from a successfully REGISTERed clients?  Through asterisk or iptables?

Comment: don't think IPtables would be a good place for this, though you may be able to finagle something with the `related` packet filtering - getting ipt to remember which connections previously registered would be painful.

Comment: Dont an INVITE for a successful REGISTER has any session id and which can help iptables to know that its a RELATED / ESTABLISHED connection request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My study so far tells me that REGISTER is only for asterisk to reach or forward the INVITES but not to authenticate an INVITE request.  When an INVITE comes, asterisk tries to check the given user name and if its a valid one, it sends a 407 (Authentication required) back to the client.  Then client inserts the password (encrypted) in the response and sends INVITE2 to server.  Now server authenticates the user and when credentials match, proceeds with establishing the call.

Conclusion:  An INVITE has no relation with REGISTER and so my idea of restricting only REGISTERED clients to send an INVITE is not possible.

As a workaround, I have written my own script.  Source is at https://github.com/naidu/JailMe

Answer (score 1):

You need change allowguest parameter to no in your sip.conf.

Check the link below for more tips about security in asterisk:

http://blogs.digium.com/2009/03/28/sip-security/

Comment: It is already set to no but though fails, still processes the INVITES from unauthorized users.

Comment: Do you have any logs? allowguest=no really does not forbid an attacker to perform an invite but dont allow an invite from an unregistered user.

Comment: Pasting the log might be pretty long here.  Do you mind if I email you the log file?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a real Session Border Controller which pays for itself quickly when you get hacked. However, if you want a "good enough" option then read on:

There is an iptables module called "string" which will search a packet for a given string. In the case of SIP we expect to see "REGISTER" in the first packet from any given address, so combine this with `-m state --state NEW` or something similar. After that, we would want keep-alive happening to ensure that connection tracking remains open (usually Asterisk sends OPTIONS, but it can send empty UDP). You want that anyway in case the client is behind NAT.

It's not the ideal solution, because iptables cannot figure out whether a registration has been successful, but at least we can insist the other guy makes an attempt at registration. One of the answers linked below shows use of the string module in iptables:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31957/test-firewall-rules-linux

You could also put an AGI script into your dialplan that does some additional checking, potentially looking at IP address and whether the extension is registered... ensure the INVITE comes from the same source IP.

Answer (score -1):

Fail2Ban is an easy way to block unwanted traffic! fail2ban check system logs for failed attempts, if there are too many (exceeding defined threshold) failed attempts in specified time from some remote IP then Fail2Pan consider it as attack, and then add that IP address in iptables to block any type of traffic from it. following links can help

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Fail2Ban+(with+iptables)+And+Asterisk

http://www.markinthedark.nl/news/ubuntu-linux-unix/70-configure-fail2ban-for-asterisk-centos-5.html

Comment: Fails2ban is already running and issue with fail2ban is that it cannot detect multiline attack.  This specific case where attack info and attacker's ip are printed in separate lines, fail2ban fails to detect.  Do you know if fail2ban can be used to configure multiline regex?  If so then some pointers on that would be helpful.

Comment: If you provide the sample, May I help

Comment: Here is the log looks like

`[2012-09-07 03:58:37] NOTICE[25439] : Changed CallerID to: 101
[2012-09-07 03:58:37] ERROR[25439] : Accountcode cannot be 0!
[2012-09-07 03:58:37] NOTICE[25439] : Caller type: Local
[2012-09-07 03:58:37] NOTICE[25439] : Localization info: cut: , add:
[2012-09-07 03:58:37] NOTICE[25439] : Localized destination: 966554295259
[2012-09-07 03:58:37] NOTICE[25439] : ============== SIPCHANINFO ===============
[2012-09-07 03:58:37] NOTICE[25439] : Peer IP: 188.249.43.9
[2012-09-07 03:58:37] NOTICE[25439] : Source IP: 188.249.43.9`

Comment: Please consider a new line before every [date] in the line.  Could not keep the formatting in the comment section.

Comment: above logs does not seems standard/core asterisk logs, may be they are result of custom dialplan / application, so without seeing that code/application I can't help. you have to search responsible code for these log and modify it to include ip address

Comment: if I have the source, dont you think this idea will trigger in my mind as well?  Moreover, I would really like to hear a solution than a workaround.  Appreciate your time and responses so far.